# Mounting volumes on Bluemix containers and sharing between them does not work

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

I've created a volume with

```
$ cf ic volume create mosquitto_config
```

This information shows up as expected:

```
$ cf ic volume list
mosquitto_config
```

Then, I've created two containers that are based on an image, which contains the `VOLUME ["/etc/mosquitto"]` line in its Dockerfile, and on which I'm able to log in via SSH:

```
$ cf ic run -p 22:22 --volume mosquitto_config:/etc/mosquitto --name ssh-test registry.ng.bluemix.net/{reg-name}/{image-name}:latest
$ cf ic run -p 22:22 --volume mosquitto_config:/etc/mosquitto --name ssh-test-2 registry.ng.bluemix.net/{reg-name}/{image-name}:latest
```

After logging in, I see the mount point `/etc/mosquitto` as directory on both containers. However, if I create a file in that directory within one container, the new file does not show up in the other container. As far as I understand the volume concept, the new file should show up in the other container. Is it currently not working or how do you set it up correctly?

Comment: Hi..Did you find any solution for this? This is exactly my problem..

Answer (score 0):

this kind of way to share volumes I think is not supported by docker.

In order to give a container access to another container’s volumes, you can simply give the –volumes-from argument to docker run. For example:

```
$ docker run -it -h NEWCONTAINER --volumes-from container-test debian /bin/bash
```

All the volumes mounted in 'container-test' will be available to 'NEWCONTAINER' (with the same mount options)

It’s important to note that it works even if the container-test is not running: a volume will never be deleted as long as a container is linked to it.

For further help check this url
http://container-solutions.com/understanding-volumes-docker/